# Adding a map to an array on Firestore Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a little trouble getting my data to save to a Firestore database. Each document in my "meetings" collection has a list of users (maps), but I cannot seem to add anything or create a new document. I read the documentation, and it said to use FieldValue.arrayUnion(), which I tried:

```
    private fun addUserToMeeting(user: User) {
        val meetingRef = database.collection("meetings").document(meetingID.toString())

        val userData = hashMapOf(
            "email" to user.email,
            "latitude" to user.latitude,
            "longitude" to user.longitude,
            "token" to user.token,
            "username" to user.username
        )

        meetingRef.update("users", FieldValue.arrayUnion(userData))
    }
```

This is called anytime an "add user to meeting" button is clicked.

Here's a picture of my schema: [image]

Has anyone got some suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What isn't working about the code? It might be easiest to explain if you show a "before" and "after" screenshot of the document when you code has run.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It's not doing anything at all. When I run it (by clicking), there's no meeting document or anything. It's as if no updates have happened whatsoever. The "meeting" under the "exampleUUIDForMeeting" was created just to see if I was connected, which is a little shrewd, but it worked in a pinch; it doesn't contain any valuable information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the document doesn't exist yet, you can't use `update` to create it. As its name implies, `update` can only be used to update an existing document.

To create a new document at a location you control, use `set`:

```
meetingRef.set(hashMapOf("users" to FieldValue.arrayUnion(userData)))
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

Comment: Whoops. That definitely was it. *facepalm* I should have caught that for sure!

Comment: I was trying add array from application side and tried many thing. Finally found solution here.